# ¿Como evitar que los botones de navegación de chrome me reproduzcan un vídeo de un iframe?

Tags: html, html5, dom, iframe, html-video

Tengo un archivo `html` con un `iframe` con el atributo `src` apuntando a un vídeo `.mp4`. Por ejemplo:

```html
<iframe src="https://VIDEO.com/media/VideoCicloNegocio.mp4" id="videoFrameLesson1"></iframe>
```

Pauso el vídeo, pero resulta que al reproducirlo, si doy clic en el botón *Atrás* del navegador no pasa nada, a menos que dé doble clic sobre él. No importa si el vídeo se encuentra pausado o detenido. El problema es que si doy clic al botón *Adelante* del navegador vuelve a reproducirlo nuevamente, a menos que dé doble clic sobre él para salir de esa vista.

Requiero utilizar las etiquetas `<iframe></iframe>` y no `<video></video>`. El problema es ese, que los botones de navegación del navegador vuelven a reproducirlo.

Comment: ¿Por qué usar un iframe?